# Is this a bug in python?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

Following in my code in Python 3.5

```
one=[]
dict={}
for i in range(int(input())):
    for j in range(9):
        one.append(int(input()) #missing one ) <- Line 5

dict[1]='hello'                 # Line 7

print(dict)
```

And following is exception thrown.

[image: Exception]

I have left out a `)` on Line 5, but error is shown to be on Line 7.

Is this a bug or there is explanation for showing error on wrong line no ?

Comment: This is a site for practical questions. No it is not a bug in python. How is this an actual problem for you?

Comment: @ReutSharabani: I kept looking at Line 7 for 30 minutes to finally figure out that error was actually on Line 5.

Comment: The main "issue" is that if the grammar from python allows multi-line statements the problem is actually line 7.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: I ran a quick test by putting `;` at end of statement and it showed error on line 5. Your explanation held true. Can you add it as answer ?

Comment: I don't see it as a practical question nor do I see my answer as a good explanation, so no :)

Comment: No, this is not a bug in Python. The language allows for *logical lines* to span multiple physical lines when you use newlines in an expression between brackets or braces, see the [*Line structure* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#line-structure) of the reference documentation. Pay particular attention to the *Implicit line joining* section. The expression started on line 5 is not complete, and can't be followed by `dict` which is why there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser doesn't know (and really, cannot know) that you forgot the closing `)`. It only knows that after skipping the whitespace, it did not expect to find an identifier (`dict`, in this case) immediately following `int(input())`. You would get basically the same error message from the more obvious error

```
>>> one.append(int("3") dict[1]=3)
File "<stdin>", line 1
  one.append(int("3") dict[1]=3)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The similar code

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    for j in range(9):
        one.append(int(input())
+ dict[1])
```

would be fine, since indentation is flexible inside the unclosed parentheses. The parser isn't responsible for guessing which parentheses might be accidentally left open; it just reports where it first finds something that isn't grammatically valid in the current context.

Comment: *it just reports where it first finds something that isn't grammatically valid in the current context.* This one line explained it all. Thanks.